# Get mAP using TensorFlow Object Detection APIs eval.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am running `python legacy/eval.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v2.config --checkpoint_dir=training/ --eval_dir=eval/`

with this configuration:

```
eval_config: {
  num_examples: 30000
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  num_visualizations: 10
  max_num_boxes_to_visualize: 5
  visualize_groundtruth_boxes: true
  eval_interval_secs: 1
  max_evals: 1
  visualization_export_dir: "eval/"
}
```

Using TensorBoard I can see the predicted bounding boxes on some images but unfortunately can't find the **mAP**. Does someone know where it is located, or if I should see it in TensorBoard?

Comment: The **mAP** will be printed to console.

Comment: Thank you I didn't look at the output. Does it also save those outputs somewhere?

Comment: If you want to save it, you can do like this. `python legacy/eval.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v2.config --checkpoint_dir=training/ --eval_dir=eval/  >mAP.txt`  this way the mAP will be saved to a text file at current directory (but also a lot of log info is saved too).